# upload multiple pictures in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

HTML Code

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="file1" size="20" />
<input type="file" name="file2" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Controller code

```
public function do_upload()
    {
            $pic1 = "Name One";
            $pic2 = "Name Two";
            $RealName = array('file1', 'file2' );
            $ChangeName = array($pic1, $pic2 );
            $arrlength = count($ChangeName);

           for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
           {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['file_name']          = $ChangeName[$x];
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 1909900;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload($RealName[$x]);
            echo $ChangeName[$x]; echo "<br>";
            echo $RealName[$x]; echo "<br>";
           }
    }
```

Trying to upload multiple pictures. Code runs correctly but I'm facing some problems in saving all pictures. The problem is saving all pictures with same name (Name One).

Answer (score 1):

try this one out. this code is I am using...

```
 private function upload_files($path, $title, $files)
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path'   => $path,
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
        'overwrite'     => 1,                       
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $image) {
        $_FILES['images[]']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['size']= $files['size'][$key];

        $fileName = $title .'_'. $image;

        $images[] = $fileName;

        $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('images[]')) {
            $this->upload->data();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $images;
}
```